# Issue pulling from Gitlab private package registry

Tags: npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, npm-install, npm-publish

We have a self-hosted GitLab (15.5.4) and I've configured everything we needed for publishing npm packages.
A CI/CD pipeline that properly creates the entry in the Package Registry.

The problem is that when I pull the package [`npm i @scope/lib`] (It doesn't change if I cast the auth token in the package.json or I pass through an environment variable as suggested in the documentation) the **unwanted** result is that the `@scope/lib` doesn't have the `dist/` folder in it!! [`node_module/@scope/lib/`].

If I browse to the Package Registry and manually download the `.tgz` file I can see that the `dist/` folder is present.
I've played around a bit with the `.npmignore` and `"prepublish"` script but I had no success and literally have no glue why this is happening.

Any tips would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify:

- The proper way is to tell `npm` to keep the `dist/` folder, bypassing the `.gitignore` file (instead of defining an `.npmignore`  [article here](https://medium.com/@jdxcode/for-the-love-of-god-dont-use-npmignore-f93c08909d8d) ) is to define a `files` entry in the `package.json` :

```json
{
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "build",
    ...
  ]
}
```

- Another ***unproper*** way to do get the result I needed is to use a `postinstall` command. But it is clearly an anti-pattern. Given that I am writing a typescript library, that is tested and then compiled by the CI, there's no need to ***re***compile it within the `postinstall` command. But it could be an hacky solution when needed.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "tsc src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

To sum up, I think it was only an `npm cache` issue or more probably a server-side cache issue, because I've run `npm cache clean --force` different times.

Hope this helps.